# Wildcard matching in Python

Tags: python, string, match, wildcard, matching

I have a class called Pattern, and within it two methods, equates and setwildcard. Equates returns the index in which a substring first appears in a string, and setwildcard sets a wild card character in a substring

So

```
p = Pattern('xyz')
t = 'xxxxxyz'
p.equates(t)
```

Returns 4

Also

```
p = Pattern('x*z', '*')
t = 'xxxxxgzx'
p.equates(t)
```

Returns 4, because * is the wildcard and can match any letter within t, as long as x and z match.
What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  In general, the "correct" way to address such a question is to implement *some* solution, and then ask for improvements on CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're essentially implementing a subset of regular expressions. Luckily, Python has a library for that built-in! If you're not familiar with how regular expressions (or, as their friends call them, regexes) work, I highly recommend you read through the [documentation for them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

In any event, the function `re.search` is, I think, exactly what you're looking for. It takes, as its first argument, a pattern to match, and, as its second argument, the string to match it in. If the pattern is matched, `search` returns an `SRE_Match` object, which, conveniently, has a `#start()` method that returns the index at which the match starts.

To use the data from your example:

```py
 import re
 start_index = re.search(r'x.z', 'xxxxxgzg').start()
```

Note that, in regexes, `.` - not `*` -- is the wildcard, so you'll have to replace them in the pattern you're using.

Answer (score 10):

Regex, like the accepted answer suggests, is one way of handling the problem. Although, if you need a simpler pattern (such as Unix shell-style wildcards), then the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) built in library can help:

Expressions:

- `*` - matches everything
- `?` - matches any single character
- `[seq]` - matches any character in `seq`
- `[!seq]` - matches any character not in `seq`

So for example, trying to find anything that would match with `localhost`:

```py
import fnmatch

my_pattern = "http://localhost*"
name_to_check = "http://localhost:8080"

fnmatch.fnmatch(name_to_check, my_pattern) # True
```

The nice part of this is that `/` is not considered a special character, so for filename/URL matching this works out quite well without having to pre-escape all slashes!

Comment: Note that fnmatch is case-insensitive: it applies os.path.normcase() before the comparison. If case-sensitivity is important, Lib/fnmatch provides fnmatch.fnmatchcase for this.